# JWTRefreshTokenBundle: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, jwt

We have a working app that successfully returns a token from `/auth/user-token` using Symfony 4 and Lexik JWT Authentication Bundle. After I install [JWTRefreshTokenBundle](https://github.com/gesdinet/JWTRefreshTokenBundle), (completing the installation up through [step 3](https://github.com/gesdinet/JWTRefreshTokenBundle#step-3-configure-your-own-routing-to-refresh-token)), however, I get this error when visiting that existing endpoint:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Reverting my files to a pre-installation state allows the app to work again.

**Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on here?**

===

Update: Attempting to run the installation through step 5 (schema update) results in this error:

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 113:
>   An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>   In PDOConnection.php line 50:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>   In PDOConnection.php line 46:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: While you were installing JWTRefreshTokenBundle, did you by any chance modify the database config? You are using .env?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am indeed using .env, and it looks like the database config was not modified during installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `mysql` and then add the following line to your `.env` file at symfony root:

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"`

Then replace the following values with desired values:

`db_user` your database user

`db_password` your database password

`db_name` your database name

Then do the following changes in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Comment: This is good advice, but all of what you have described is already in place. And doing a `git status` shows that these files are not modified during installation of the bundle. It's very strange behavior.

Comment: Your `.env` file does not modified during installation but it is possible that your new Mysql server has different configuration and you have to update `.env` file according new configuration.

Comment: That's funny -- pulling fresh changes from our develop branch seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks to you being the only person to give an answer, you get the bounty :-)

Comment: YW Patrick, Please mark my answer as desired answer and vote for it. @Patrickatwork